# How to make a dynamic motd-module in Puppet?

Tags: puppet, motd

We are using Puppet to generate our /etc/motd file. Unfortunately the hostnames do not always have the same length.

This creates a /etc/motd with sometimes a space too much or too little after the hostname.

```
 #############################################
 ##  This server is managed from Amsterdam  ##
 #############################################
 #############################################
 ##               web-tst-01                 ##
 #############################################
```

What can be done so that the number of spaces is dynamically changed based on the length of the hostname?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. use an erb template to generate motd if you are not yet doing it.
2. generate the host line with ruby code, assuming hostname has your hostname

   ```
   <% (hostname.center 40, " ").center 44, '#' %>
   ```

Comment: Hello, placing <% (hostname.center 40, " ").center 44, '#' %> in /etc/puppet/modules/motd/templates/motd.erb generates an empty line.

Comment: That means your hostname is not set.

Comment: This is not true. The entire line is empty... hostname is set, because <%= hostname %> works fine.

Comment: My bad, the = after % was missing! <%= (hostname.center 43, " ").center 45, '#' %>